# In javascript, how to set function parameter names when creating function via "new Function()"?

Tags: javascript, function, parameters, new-operator

Trying to set the parameter names in a function, via `new Function(fnBody)`, to correlate to dynamic function-body-text variables.

```
const myFnBody = " return myParam; ";  // dynamic fn-text, expecting 'myParam' variable.
const myFunc = new Function(myFnBody);  // create the function with the body-text.
const myParamVal = "Hello world.";  // setup argument
console.log(myFunc(myParamVal));   // output: undefined, not 'Hello world.' as desired.
```

console output is `undefined` because "myParam" isn't linked to the first argument (arguments[0]) in the function call context.

Want function to assign first arg (arguments[0]) to a "myParam" parameter, as in:

```
const myFunc = function (myParam) { return myParam; }
```

I need this for running dynamic code written with parameter-names in mind: similar to "require" and "exports" from CommonJS. The code is expecting values passed with specific parameter/variable names.

The best i've been able to come up with is to pre-set a variable via the `arguments` collection, then add the actual dynamic function-text:

```
let dynamicFnText = {SOME USER DEFINED FN BODY-TEXT, such as "return myParam;"};
let myFnBody = "";  // start the fn-body as text (string)
myFnBody += "const myParam = arguments[0];";  // prefix a parameter value via the arguments
myFnBody += dynamicFnText;  // append the dynamic fn text, which expects 'myParam' variable.

let myFunc = new Function(myFnBody);
let myParam = "Hello world.";
console.log(myFunc(myParam));  // 'Hello world."
```

Using `eval`: Yes, i could use `eval()`, as in:

```
let myFunc = eval("(function (myParam) {" + dynamicFnText + "})");  // fn with 'myParam'
```

However, i'm trying to avoid the "evil" `eval()` function. Should i not be concerned about using `eval()` in this manner?

I guess i was expecting some sort of `.setParameters()` method on the function (`new Function()`) instance. Or something like `new Function(paramNamesArray, fnBody)`.

Any help appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: [It's part of how the Function constructor works.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/Function)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just specify the parameter name in addition to the function body when invoking `new Function`:

```js
const myFnBody = " return myParam; ";  // dynamic fn-text, expecting 'myParam' variable.
const myFunc = new Function('myParam', myFnBody);  // create the function with the body-text.
const myParamVal = "Hello world.";  // setup argument
console.log(myFunc(myParamVal));
```

Since this comes from the user, make sure the user provides a list of arguments their function will accept, then list them in the `new Function` argument list as needed.

> Should i not be concerned about using eval() in this manner?

No, you shouldn't - `new Function` is just as unsafe as `eval`. If you'll be using `new Function`, you may as well be using `eval` (from a security standpoint), since it allows for the execution of dynamic (and possibly unsafe) code.

Answer (score 3):

> Or something like new Function(paramNamesArray, fnBody)

Close! It would be `new Function(...paramNamesArray, fnBody)`.

The [`Function` constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/Function) supports multiple arguments. The *last* argument is the function body. Any arguments before that are the names of the parameters.

So in your case with `myParam`, you'd pass `"myParam:` as the first argument:

```
const myFunc = new Function("myParam", myFnBody);
```

Live Example:

```js
const myFnBody = " return myParam; ";
const myFunc = new Function("myParam", myFnBody);
const myParamVal = "Hello world.";
console.log(myFunc(myParamVal));
```

Going back to your `paramNamesArray` concept, you might do:

```
const myFunc = new Function(...paramNamesArray, myFnBody);
```

Live Example:

```js
const myFnBody = " return myParam; ";
const paramNamesArray = ["myParam"];
const myFunc = new Function(...paramNamesArray, myFnBody);
const myParamVal = "Hello world.";
console.log(myFunc(myParamVal));
```

---

> However, i'm trying to avoid the "evil" eval() function. Should i not be concerned about using eval() in this manner?

`new Function` is only the **tiniest** bit less of a problem than using `eval`. Both allow arbitrary code execution, which means both require that you **fully trust** the code you're evaluating with them. You don't want to take code from User A and run that code in User B's context (unless User B expressly expects and allows that, like when we click "Run code snippet" here on SO). The **very** minor way that `new Function` is slightly less problematic than `eval` is that it can't be used to access things in local scope, and `eval` can. (You can fix that by using *indirect* eval, which also can't use local scope.)

There are times when `eval` or `new Function` is what you need to use, but those use cases are ***very*** rare. Bottom line: If you're worried about using `eval`, worry about using `new Function`. It's *(almost)* just as "bad."